# Need implementation like this in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, window-functions

I have a table like this:

[image]

And I want this - I am trying with PIVOT but not getting the expected results:

[image]

Comment: Please show what you tried

Comment: _I am trying with PIVOT but not getting expected.?_ -> Please [edit] your question and show us what you have tried.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do conditional aggregation. I suspect that you want:

```
select 
    sbno,
    max(case when test_name = 'Test1' then val end) test1,
    max(case when test_name = 'Test2' then val end) test2,
    max(case when test_name = 'Test3' then val end) test3
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by sbno, test_name order by val) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by sbno, rn
order by sbno, rn
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=af516671d4787cc5c75352cd60e2130e)**:

```
sbno | test1 | test2 | test3
---: | :---- | :---- | :----
   1 | A     | B     | C    
   1 | D     | null  | null 
   2 | A     | B     | C    
   2 | D     | null  | null
```

Comment: Not working its working like Pivot only...

Comment: @SANDEEP: see my updated answer (and demo).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `row_number()` and `PIVOT`

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select *
              ,RowNr = (row_number() over (partition by SBNO order by VAL) -1 ) / 3 
         from YourTable
       ) src
 Pivot (max(VAL) for Test_Name in ([Test1],[Test2],[Test3] ) ) pvt
 Order By SBNO,RowNr
```

**Returns**

```
SBNO    RowNr   Test1   Test2   Test3
1       0       A       B       C
1       1       D       NULL    NULL
2       0       A       B       C
2       1       D       NULL    NULL
```